# HMS Core - About the usage of API key in Map Kit and Site Kit

Tags: android, mapkit, huawei-mobile-services

## Background

I tried to use only HMS to build a map app similar to Google Map app. I proved that only HMS is enough to do it.

When I was building the app, I faced a problem. Of course I solved it at last. But I want to share my experience.

## Target Function

- Map : [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit)
- Guester : [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-MapKit)
- Compass : [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-MapKit)
- Zoom : [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-MapKit)
- Location Now : [Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-locationkit)
- Keyword Search : [Site Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-sitekit/)
- Location Search : [Site Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/jp/hms/huawei-sitekit/)

## Send API Key

API Key is need for Map Kit and Site Kit. The following is how to use API key described in official document.

#### Map Kit

Method 1

```
// In the entrance class (inherited from android.app.Application) of the app,
// call the setApiKey method in the overridden onCreate() method. 
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Set the API key.
        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API Key");
    }
}
```

Method 2

```
// Send API Key in Fragment or in MapView
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the API key before calling setContentView.
        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API Key");
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
    }
```

Basically, just run MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API Key")

#### Site Kit

```
// Declare a SearchService object.
private SearchService searchService; 
// Instantiate the SearchService object.
searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(this, "API key");
```

## Test Result (Failed)

The following is the result.

Map is able to show.

[image]

However, keyword search is not working.

[image]

## Reason

The reason is the API key of Site Kit. Map Kit uses API key without encoding, but Site Kit needs encoded API key.

## Test Result (Succeeded)

Using encoded API key and send it to Site Kit as following.

```
searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(this, URLEncoder.encode("API key", "utf-8"));
```

Keyword search result is displayed.

[image]

Comment: I want to get API Key from agconnect-services.json file programatically . How can I do that?

Comment: @BayarŞahintekin last year you can use 
`AGConnectServicesConfig config = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(this);` but now this seems to be deprecated